# Problema formato imput date

Tags: html5, angularjs, bootstrap

Mi problema es que utilizo esto:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="fechaInicio" ng-model="cita.fechaInicio" />
```

Pero me visualiza la fecha en este formato: 2018/02/02 y me da error no quiere guardarlo entonces necesito cambiar el formato a 2018-02-02.

He intentado hacerlo de mil maneras incluso intentando importar librerías con datepickers externos pero no lo consigo hacer porque no los integro bien a ver si me echáis un cable, porque quiero que salga el calendario para elegir la fecha.

Añado info:
He conseguido que me visualice el calendario con le fecha correcta todo perfecto con el datepicker de bootstrap pero a la hora de darle a añadir no me añade la cita eso es porque se origina algun tipo de error(Estoy utilizando AngularJS(Angular1)). Aqui el codigo:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="fechaInicio">Fecha de la cita:</label>

      <div class="input-group date fecha">
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="fechaInicio" ng-model="cita.fechaInicio"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.fecha').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        language: "es"
      });
      </script>

    </div>
```

La consola no me da error, y no se exactamente porque me falla.

Comment: Por favor agrega tu contenido js, es imposible dar una respuesta si no colocas tu contenido...

Comment: esque no he utilizado nada de js, es simplemente el datepicker que te ofrece pro defecto html5

Answer (score 1):

si  estas  utilizando datepickers puedes  darle formato ahí

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    startDate: '-3d'
});
```

o también dar  formato desde el input ejemplo

```
<input class="datepicker" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
```

Ós dejo  la  liga
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: No me funciona, me sale la barra del date y eso pero no se me despliega el calendario.

Comment: He editado el post, ahora me funciona el calendario pero no se añade la cita.